# How can I fix the problem " Specified file could not be found" in Python file?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a project written in Python to capture the video of my webcam camera using opencv.
When i run this file it had an eror:
**Error running 'Capture_image': Cannot run program"C:/Python/python.exe"(in directory"D:/Vien/Python/Python Program"): CreateProcess error = 2, specified file could not be found**

Before this I've install 2 version of Python that is Python 3.8.2 and Python 3.6.8 and set up the interpreter with Python 3.6.8 and the link is " C:/Python 3.6.8 64bit/Python.exe "

Moreover, when I install Python I've install the Python 3.8.2 version first and create a directory to put it in disk C with file" Python" then I changed the name into "Python 3.8.2"
So I don't know what caused this error and how to fix this.
Can anyone realize what mistake I've made?
Thank you!

Here is the code( But I don't think the code caused this error):

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(5)
cap.release()
```

Comment: Please post the code that produced this error.

Comment: @ Ashwin Geet D'Sa I've posted the code as your request.